# Vue.JS - TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'undefined' in Laravel Object

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I want to pass an object from Laravel to Vue.js, then use it in `:v-for="option in this.options"`. I am able to pass the object from my Laravel blade to Vue.js component and display it in the console, but when I want to use the object in `v-for` I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'undefined' in [{"id":1,"poll_id":1,"content":"Black","created_at":"2019-12-15 02:53:52","updated_at":"2019-12-15 02:53:52"},{"id":2,"poll_id":1,"content":"Blue","created_at":"2019-12-15 02:53:52","updated_at":"2019-12-15 02:53:52"}]
    at Proxy.render (app.js:48972)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (app.js:52735)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (app.js:53251)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:53662)
    at new Watcher (app.js:53651)
    at mountComponent (app.js:53258)
    at VueComponent../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js.Vue.$mount (app.js:58228)
    at VueComponent../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js.Vue.$mount (app.js:61113)
    at init (app.js:52315)
    at createComponent (app.js:55157)
```

Vue.JS component

```
<template>
    <div :v-for="option in this.options">
        <div v-if="option" class="option mt-4">
            {{ option }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'id', 'options'
        ],
        mounted() {
            this.options = JSON.parse(this.options);
            console.log(this.options);
        },
    }
</script>
```

Laravel blade

```
<options :id="{{ $poll->id }}" :options="'{{ json_encode($poll->options) }}'"></options>
```

`console.log(this.options)` returns

```
(2) [{…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
    0: {…} // id, poll_id, content, created_at, updated_at
    1: {…} // id, poll_id, content, created_at, updated_at
    length: 2
    __ob__: Observer {value: Array(2), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
    __proto__: Array
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few mistakes in this block:

```
<div :v-for="option in this.options">
   <div v-if="option" class="option mt-4">
       {{ option }}
   </div>
</div>
```

You have to fix the following:

- Change `:v-for` to just `v-for`
- Remove `this.` from `this.options` because you only should
  use `this.` in the `script` area
- Put this whole block inside another `<div>` because there should be only 1  element inside `<template>` tag. So since you're using a loop, multiple elements will be rendered